# Overloading of template function in template class

Tags: c++, templates, g++, language-lawyer, clang++

I have a templated operator in templated class and I want to change its behavior for specific type. My code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename N>
struct A {
  int x;
  template<typename T>
  A& operator<<(const T& t) {
    x += static_cast<int>(t);
    return *this;
  }
};


enum class B {
  s,t
};

template <typename N>
A<N>& operator<<(A<N>& a, const B& b) {
  a.x -= static_cast<int>(b);
  return a;
}

int main() {
  A<int> a{3};
  std::cout << (a<<1).x << " " << (a << B::s).x;
}
```

g++-4.9 compiles it fine but clang-3.6 complains that it's ambiguous.

Note, that if class is not templated, than both of compilers compile it fine.

What is correct behavior?

Comment: I understand the quetstion as: is this overloading (ambiguous, clang is right) or specialization (so gcc is right)?

Comment: @marom a specialization would have a different syntax, possinly involving `template<>` with an empty set of arguments.

Comment: @n.m. You mean function call? Why should then clang complain?

Comment: It's not a question of overloading vs specialization. I think Clang's ambiguity warning is because it can't work out the partial ordering on the member template function with a template parameter on the right vs the free template function with a template parameter on the left. I'm not sure which is the right behaviour though.

Comment: @marom no, i mean the definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short summary: I believe this is a gcc bug in the template partial ordering rules, and that clang is correct. I filed [bug 66914](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66914), although it's probably a duplicate of [bug 53499](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53499) which I didn't notice until afterwards.

---

In the call

```
a << B::s;
```

We have two viable candidates:

```
template <typename T> A<int>::operator<<(const T& );
template <typename N> operator<<(A<N>&, const B& );
```

You can rewrite the member function to take a reference to the instance as the first argument, and write out both as instantiatons. So we have:

```
template <> operator<<(A<int>&, const B& ); // [T = B]
template <> operator<<(A<int>&, const B& ); // [N = int]
```

Since both are viable candidates, let's go through the rules in [over.match.best] to determine which one is the best viable candidate:

> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function
>   F2 if for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then
>
> — for some argument j, ICSj(F1) is a better conversion sequence than ICSj(F2), or, if not that,

Nope, both take the exact same arguments, so the conversion sequences are identical.

> — the context is an initialization by user-defined conversion [ ... ]

Nope, irrelevant.

> — the context is an initialization by conversion function [ ... ]

Nope, irrelevant.

> — F1 is not a function template specialization and F2 is a function template specialization, or, if not that,

Nope, *both* are function template specializations.

> — F1 and F2 are function template specializations, and the function template for F1 is more specialized
>   than the template for F2 according to the partial ordering rules described in 14.5.6.2.

This is the most complicated of the rules. Ultimately, neither is more specialized than the other. Why? The member function is effectively:

```
template <typename T> A<int>& operator<<(A<int>&, const T& );
```

If we synthesized a type for `T` (call it `Unique1`), deduction would fail against the free function (since `Unique1` wouldn't match `B`). On the other side, if we synthesized a type for `N` (call it `Unique2`), deduction would fail against the member function (since `Unique2` wouldn't match `int`).

Since neither function is more specialized than the other, we've run out of bullet points. The function call should be ambiguous, this is a gcc bug.

Comment: Why `N` shouldn't participate in template resolution is first case?

Comment: everytime i see a bug in gcc i also find it in msvc++ and both always assume the right call.

Comment: @RiaD Because only template arguments are deduced - in the first case, you're calling a member template on a class template - you don't deduce the `N` (that's given), just the `T`.

Comment: @RiaD In the same way that if we'd written `operator<<(const B&);` as a member function, that member function would *not* be a member function template.

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
template <typename N>
A<N>& operator<<(A<N>& a, const B& b) {
  a.x -= static_cast<int>(b);
  return a;
}
```

is not an overload of your member operator (I'm sure there is a more correct way to say it from the standardese point of view), and not a specialization, it is a global template operator that participates in overload resolution.

From that point of view both are equally perfect matches so I think clang is correct.

Comment: You have "This is not an overload" and "it... participates in overload resolution." It either is or isn't an overload, pick one.

Comment: I was trying to highlight the fact that it is not a member of the class in response to the title of the post which could be read as if OP thought he is overloading the member of the template not creating a global operator. Sorry, as I said my standardese is not very strong.